# Why cant we have wrapper class objects as constant?

Tags: java

In Java 7, for the given code:

```
final Integer i=9;
final int x=5;

switch(x){
case 1:
case i://compilation error is thrown here 
}
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: because `i` is now an Integer object rather than a primitive value. You can switch on primitives, support for ONLY String object is added in Java 7 not just any other object

Comment: And `i` is not a constant, even if `Integer` was allowed.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer i = 9;`

With this `i` is now a reference to Integer object and it's not a valid type to switch on in Java.

Following are the valid variable types, you can Switch on

1. Convertible ints - int, byte,short,char
2. Enums
3. String constants - support added in Java 7

Other than these valid values, you cannot just switch on any other Object

Comment: No, even the wrapper for the corresponding primitives is being supported now.

Comment: You mean something like `switch(i)` where i is an Integer object, that's because of Auto-Unboxing, compiler does that for you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason I was looking for:

Wrapper objects such as Integer cannot be used in a case statement as they are not compile time constants(because the boxing and un boxing happens at runtime). hence you can only use primitives that are compile time constants which
 must also be final.

Comment: As case labels accept String objects since 1.7, the second half of this post, "hence you can only use primitives", is a sort of obsolete...

Answer (score 0):

In many languages **`switch` statements represent a constant time lookup over a set of compile time constants**.

The javac compiler will transform the switch statement into a very efficient bytecode representation and for that optimization the compile time constant is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1) switch case doesnt support any Object type as case, more over it supports primitive variables as constants and literals.

2) From Java 7 it supports Strings.

```
 ex:-
    final int num1=10;
    int x=0;
    int num2=5;
    final Integer y=20;

    switch (num2) {
    case num1: //logic  
    case x ://logic ----> Compile time Error since it is not final/constant.
    case y ://logic ----> Compile time Error,since it is of object type.
    default:
        //logic      
    }
```